# Want to display HTML code for websites upon click a banner image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display banner HTML code in popup for websites when someone click on the banner.

For example a banner is

```
<img src="https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif">
```

I want to display the following data in popup on clicking the banner image.

```
<a href="myweb.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif" border=0></a><br>[url=https://myweb.com] [img]https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif[/img] [/url]
```

I don't have any knowledge about how this issue can be solved. Please help me in solving this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: there are a lot of librarys shaowbox is nice.. but maybe there is more..  See here answer to someone use shadowbox as popover http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608229/shadowbox-js-as-a-popup

Comment: Your answer is quite different to my situation. I need a banner to be clickable and in popup don't want any shadowbox which is playable. I want to show HTML code for clicked image in popup so people can copy it to display on their websites.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to display static text in a popup, would a confirm or alert prompt work e.g:

```
<a href="myweb.com" target="_blank" onClick="showHTML()">
  <img src="https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif" border=0>
</a>

<script>
function showHTML(){
    alert("<img src=\"https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif\" border=0>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is giving error when I am trying to add anchor for example.

<script>
function showHTML(){
  alert('<a href="myweb.com" target="_blank" onClick="showHTML()">
  <img src="https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif" border=0>
</a>');
}
</script>

Comment: Expected '"' and instead saw '''.
  alert('<img src="https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif" border=0>');
4.9
Expected '/'.
</script>

Comment: Visit http://www.jslint.com/ to check the error by input.
<script>
function showHTML(){
  alert('<img src="https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif" border=0>');
}
</script>

Comment: jslint complicates things and is outside my area of expertise but if the double quotes are the problem, try changing the alert statement to:  alert("<img src=\"https://myweb.com/images/banners/1.gif\" border=0>"); I'll edit my answer for this as well.

Comment: When I click on this [link](https://mobilemonkey.com/case-studies/mobilemonkey) I will see that after a couple of seconds a narrow strip/bar will appear at the bottom of the page. I have a website built with `Nunjucks` template (`html`, `javascript`, etc) that I would like to place a simple unobtrusive banner (narrow strip) on its homepage, to appear after a few second, where I can provide a little text or link or invitation to a survey. Is the answer to this post how I should do it, or is what I am looking for a totally different thing?